# Color smoosh with ppm in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do the following:
I have to create a ppm file in c++. This file must smoosh a color (like a color gradient).
So far I've been able to create the file and it returns me a ppm with almost the color smoosh that I want. I think the problem is in the for loops. Thank you in advance.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Color
{
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;
};

void smoosh(int rows, int cols, Color leftColor, Color rightColor, string filename);

int main()
{
    Color leftColor;
    Color rightColor;
    int rows;
    int cols;

    cout << "Left Color: " << endl;
    cin >> leftColor.red >> leftColor.green >> leftColor.blue;
    cout << "Right Color: " << endl;
    cin >> rightColor.red >> rightColor.green >> rightColor.blue;
    cout << "Height: " << endl;
    cin >> rows;
    cout << "Width: " << endl;
    cin >> cols;

    string filename;
    cout << "File Name: " << endl;
    cin >> filename;
    smoosh(rows, cols, leftColor, rightColor, filename);


    return 0;
}

void smoosh(int rows, int cols, Color leftColor, Color rightColor, string filename)
{
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open(filename);

    fout << "P3" << endl;
    fout << cols << " " << rows << endl;
    fout << "255" << endl;

    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = 0; i <= rows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= cols; j++)
        {
            int r;
            int g;
            int b;
            r=static_cast<float>(leftColor.red)+((static_cast<float>(j)/cols)*(static_cast<float>(rightColor.red)-static_cast<float>(leftColor.red)));
            g=static_cast<float>(leftColor.green)+((static_cast<float>(j)/cols)*(static_cast<float>(rightColor.green)-static_cast<float>(leftColor.green)));
            b=static_cast<float>(leftColor.blue)+((static_cast<float>(j)/cols)*(static_cast<float>(rightColor.blue)-static_cast<float>(leftColor.blue)));
            fout<<r<<" "<<g<<" "<<b<<" ";
        }
    }
}
```

What i am trying to make it look like:

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific to what your problem is? How can we know the exact color gradient you want it to be?

Comment: Sorry, you can try with this:
Left Color: 255 255 0
Right Color: 200 0 125 
Height: 100
Width: 500
File Name: example.ppm

Comment: That should return a gradient from yellow to red.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't post images because I'm new. I've found on google something similar: http://photo.net/general-comments/attachment/13443706/redcompare2ps.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was solved just removing the "=" from the for loops. Thanks